# Access .NET web server using an HTTP connection

Tags: android, httpconnection

Can we access a .NET web server using an HTTP connection on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's certainly no reason why you couldn't.  The server-side technology doesn't matter (well, *shouldn't* matter... I guess a poor design on the web application might make it matter).  If you can connect to a web server, then you can connect to a web server.

Incidentally, ".NET web server" doesn't seem entirely accurate.  IIS?  Apache with mod_mono?  Again, from a client perspective it shouldn't matter.

Comment: acutally am working on integration part and my web server is build using .net. i have login page i have to get authenticated with webserver and if valid user than redirect to home page can you tel me how to do this i have no idea

Comment: @user671005: So it's a custom web server then?  Should still be fine, as long as it's a proper HTTP server.  As for how to do this from the client side, I have no idea.  I'm not familiar with Android development, though I doubt it's terribly different from most other modern platforms.  You should be able to POST the authentication request (over SSL, I hope) and parse the response to perform whatever logic is needed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can access a .net web server using http connection on Android.